# Importing angular in typescript using webpack load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, webpack

Hi folks on the Internet! Today I am presenting you another problem! (Yay?)

I am using webpack with the ts-loader to compile typescript code. However when I'm importing angular like this:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
angular.module("app", []);
```

It is actually importing 2 scripts as presented below:

```
[18:11:21] Starting 'build'...
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.0.6 and C:\testProject\tsconfig.json
[18:11:24] [webpack] Hash: 155db0dc394ae32ae9e6
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 2845ms
 Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.js  3.11 MB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} app.js (main) 1.19 MB [rendered]
    [0] ./app/app.module.ts 2.26 kB {0} [built]
    [1] ./~/angular/index.js 48 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/angular/angular.js 1.19 MB {0} [built]
```

- `index.js`: The entry point of the angular library code
- `angular.js`: The angular library

This is a problem because `index.js` also loads the angular library in which the result is the angular library loaded **twice**.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
entry: "./app/app.module.ts",

output: {
  publicPath: "/lib/",
  path: path.join(__dirname,"lib"),
  filename: "app.js"
},

// source map
devtool: "#inline-source-map",

module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      // Exclude node modules
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      loader: 'ts-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      // Exclude node modules
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      loader: 'raw-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mis-understand how webpack works. All modules are executed once no matter how many times you require them. For example if you do:

```
 var angular = require('angular');
 var anotherAngular = require('angular');
```

The `angular` script will only really execute once, and the result "cached" for all subsequent calls to `require`.

In your case what you are seeing is perfectly normal. When you load angular from an npm package, the npm package uses the `index.js` which looks like:

```
require('./angular');
module.exports = angular;
```

It is common in npm packages to have a minimal `index.js` that just re-exports another script. When you are loading with webpack webpack will load `index.js` which will in turn load `angular.js` and return the result. This shouldn't cause you any problems, and nothing is really getting loaded twice.